# How do I preview the action bar menu items in landscape orientation?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I am working on my UI design and want to preview my main menu icons. I can change my menu_main display to design and preview them but there does not seem to be an option to change the orientation to landscape.

[image]

When I preview activity_main I can rotate the view to the landscape but it does not have the menu items.

How can I preview the design of the menu in landscape mode in Android Studio 3.4.2?